# How to generate a side-by-side view of a Google-translated webpage in Angular

Tags: angular, google-translate

We would like to embed Google-translated webpages in our Angular application using a side-by-side view, rather than just a link. For example, https://www-amazon-com.translate.goog/dp/B07NLNRWBV?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=zh-CN&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp

However, built-in html tags such as iframe do not work, as these websites prohibit embedding via such html elements.

Is there a solution for this?

I asked about this in the Google group for Google Translate API, but they directed me to StackOverflow.